# Cordova PhoneGap Android Callback with data

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I cant figure out how to get data back from JAVA to javascript so I can update the UI using Cordova on Android. here are two buttons, as they are pressed they increment the position counter which I want to return to the UI and update the screen but cannot figure out how its returned.

I thought I could just add the switchPos to the callback but cant seem to pick it up anywhere in javascript, I was planning to write the value to the UI with a ".innerHTML =" statement.

Here is the plugin javascript.

```
cordova.define(‘myplugin', function (require, exports, module) {
   module.exports = {

    switch1: function (success, failure) {
    cordova.exec(success, failure, “MyPlugin", “switch1”, []);
    },

    switch2: function (success, failure) {
    cordova.exec(success, failure, “MyPlugin", “switch2”, []);
    }


  };
});
```

Here is the javascript that calls them.

```
 var myplugin = cordova.require('myplugin');

 var myapp = {

appButton1: function(){
     myplugin.switch1();
},

appButton2: function(){
     myplugin.switch2();
}

};
```

Here is the JAVA code for the plugin.

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

// actions
private static final String SWITCH1 = “switch”1;
private static final String SWITCH2 = “switch”2;

// callbacks
private CallbackContext connectCallback;

// Switch Counters
public static int switchPos1 = 1;
public static int switchPos2 = 1;


@Override
public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    boolean validAction = true;

    if (action.equals(SWITCH1)) {
    Log.d("Valid Action = SWITCH1 Pos: “ + switchPos1);
    switchPos1++;
    callbackContext.success(switchPos1);

} else if (action.equals(SWITCH2)) {
    Log.d("Valid Action = SWITCH2 Pos: “ + switchPos2);
    switchPos2++;
    callbackContext.success(switchPos2);

} else { 
    validAction = false;
}

return validAction;

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call the plugin you have to pass the success and failure functions:

```
var myplugin = cordova.require('myplugin');

 var myapp = {

appButton1: function(){
     myplugin.switch1(function(data){alert(data);},function(error){alert(error);});
},

appButton2: function(){
     myplugin.switch2(function(data){alert(data);},function(error){alert(error);});
}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this one

Firstly you need to declare your custom plugin in config.xml. You can found this file in res > xml folder.

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.Phonegap.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Then you need to implement plugin by using Java- code

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
            throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("sayHello")){
            try {
                String responseText = "Hello world, " + args.getString(0);
                callbackContext.success(responseText);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally we calling a plugin from javascript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```